# Gradle: Copy subproject resources

Tags: java, gradle, task, dependency-management

So I have a project that contains a few subprojects that I am using Gradle with.  What I would like to do is copy the resources from subprojectA to the main subprojectB.  My structure looks like so.

```
Application
  \subprojectA
      \src\main\resources\blah
  \subprojectB
       \src\main\...
```

What I want to do, is when my application builds and compiles, overlay the resources folder from subprojectA into the main application's resource folder.

I've tried creating a Gradle task which looks like

```
task copyExtractorResources(type: Copy) {
    from 'extractors/src/main/resources/'
    into 'main/build/resources'
 }
```

and while it runs, I can't for the life of me find out how to say "Hey, always do this task before building"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simpler way to accomplish this is simply to tell the existing `processResources` task to include your additional resources.

```
processResources {
    from 'extractors/src/main/resources'
}
```

However, for future reference you could implement your original solution by simply adding `jar.dependsOn copyExtractorResources` to your build script.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Turns out, I was trying to solve this problem in order to solve another problem.  I've figured it out, and I stumbled upon the "dependsOn" method right after posting this question.  Thanks for your help!